# How to extract field in Android studio for Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, shortcut

In Android Studio, I want to extract the field `toolbar` from the method in class scope like java

```
val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.my_toolbar)
        setupToolBar(toolbar)
```

I put the cursor on the toolbar and right click to find the function to extract fields but no luck. **(Refactor -> Extract -> No Fields Extract)**

Appreciate any advice or comment for it.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this.it will work

```
  val toolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar) as Toolbar
  setupToolBar(toolbar)
```

Comment: It seems it is in local scope. How can I put it in class scope.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ID of `toolbar` directly as variable (it works for me).

`setupToolBar(my_toolbar)`

Answer (score 0):

This is the equivalent of Extract Field in Java (should be Extract Property in Kotlin) and captured in the below ticket,but it's still not fixed:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13309

I think it's fairly important, but something keeps them from fixing it.